# 'Create Node' form as part of panelized page

Tags: panels

How can I add 'create node' to a panelized page? 
I basically want to have the 'create x CT' form at the top, with a view of submitted nodes below.  What's the best way to achieve this with panels?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a Context **Node add form** to your panel and afterwards, you can select the appropriate edit form in the 'Form' section when you add content to the panel.